# VS SR Report joining data from multiple Data sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Wondering if anyone can help me, I am currently learning, SRSS Reports and have been tasked with a Pay & Display vehicle registration report, for staff and student carparks, to show if they are registered for P&D. I have the report laid out as a 3 table column; Name, Vehicle Number and Vehicle Registration. I have from the below code set out in my datasets the Vehicle Number and Vehicle Registrations pulling through, with a parameter to filter out if is staff or student pay and display. However I am having difficulty with pulling the Staff and Student names into one name column as they are through two different datasets. Can anyone be of help at all please? TIA

```
**-- Pay & Display Carpark Details Dataset**
SELECT * FROM Carpark_Vehicles
WHERE VehicleCustNo IN (SELECT CustID FROM [dbo].[Carpark_Customer]
                        WHERE CarParkID IN (SELECT CarParkID FROM [dbo].[Carpark_CarPark]
                                            WHERE CTypeID IN ('PD', 'SPD')))
                        --and CTypeID IN (@Carpark_type))
**--Vehicle Details Dataset**
SELECT 
 Carpark_Vehicles.VehicleID
      ,Carpark_Vehicles.RegNo
    ,VehicleCustNo
 FROM
  Carpark_Vehicles
WHERE CarPark_Vehicles.RegNo = @RegNo

**--Staff details dataset**
SELECT
StaffDetails_StaffandLeaverDetails.StaffNumber
  ,StaffDetails_StaffandLeaverDetails.LastName
  ,StaffDetails_StaffandLeaverDetails.Name1
FROM
  StaffDetails_StaffandLeaverDetails 

**--Student details dataset**
SELECT
  Student_CurrentStudentDetails.StudentNumber
  ,Student_CurrentStudentDetails.StudentID
  ,Student_CurrentStudentDetails.LastName
  ,Student_CurrentStudentDetails.FirstName
FROM
  Student_CurrentStudentDetails

**--Carpark permit type (Pay & Display) parameter**
SELECT DISTINCT
CTypeID, CASE CTypeID WHEN 'abc' THEN 'Students' WHEN 'abc' THEN 'Staff' END AS Label
FROM
  Carpark_Customer
WHERE CTypeID IN ('abc', 'Abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

For your req I just took some sample data. This entire example will give you Idea how to achieve your final result.

Note: this is just showing you way how to achieve it, you have to modify as per your req.

Student and Staff Info from 2 different Tables

[image: Student and Staff Info from 2 different Tables]

Registration Info from another separate Table

[image: Registration Info from another separate Table]

Your Final Result when Student as parameter is selected

[image: Your Final Result when Student as parameter is selected]

Your Final Result when Staff as parameter is selected

[image: Your Final Result when Staff as parameter is selected]

Now how did I achieved this?

My Design for Final Result

[image]

Row visibilty expression for your final result Table in SSRS

[image]

Expressiion as below

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value=1,
IIF(Isnothing(Lookup(Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!Name.Value, "DSStudentInfo")),true,false),
IIF(Isnothing(Lookup(Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!Name.Value, "DSStaffInfo")),true,
false)
)
```

first Name column visibility

[image]

second column name visibility

[image]

First Name data value expression

[image]

```
=Lookup(Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!Name.Value, "DSStudentInfo")
```

second name data value expression

[image]

```
=Lookup(Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!PersonId.Value,Fields!Name.Value, "DSStaffInfo")
```

Comment: Thanks AnkUser for all your help much appreciated :)

Comment: @sql-me did it helped??